# I want to write code to replace some arguments

Tags: python

My start of the code goes like that:

```
complementDNA = originalDNA.replace('a' , 't' , 't' , 'a')
```

and it says on the running

```
  complementDNA = originalDNA.replace('a' , 't' , 't' , 'a')
TypeError: replace() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Read docs about `str.replace()` (assuming `originalDNA` is a string)

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to achieve with the replacement? A before and after for the string would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `originalDNA` is a string, then I think you dont want to replace, you want to translate, ie:

```
originalDNA = 'atgta'  # Know nothing about DNA btw
complement_table = str.maketrans('at', 'ta')
complementDNA = originalDNA.translate(complement_table)
# complementDNA is now 'tagat'
```

To give a brief explanation, maketrans takes at least 2 arguments and at most 3. The first two arguments are strings of equal length where each character of the first argument will be replaced by the character at the same position in the second argument. The optional third argument is other string with the characters you want to delete.

So, for example `str.maketrans('ac', 'ca', 'b')` will replace `'a'` to `'c'`, `'c'` to `'a'` and delete all `'b'`.
`'abccba'.translate(str.maketrans('ac', 'ca', 'b'))` will then be `'caac'`

Answer (score 0):

Replace takes two arguments. replace(before, after).
You will have to do it for 'a' and 't' separately and for 't' to 'a' separately. That would not give the right answer. One way you can do it is by converting the DNA to a list of characters and iterating over them checking manually to convert 'a' to 't' and 't' to 'a'. Like so

```
DNAlist = []

for character in originalDNA:
    DNAlist.append(character)

for i in range(0, len(DNAlist)):
    if DNAlist[i] == 'a':
        DNAlist [i] = 't'
    elif DNAlist[i] == 't':
        DNAlist[i] = 'a'

# Convert the list back to string
DNAstring = ''.join(DNAlist)
```

Although I would suggest to use lists until you have to convert the DNA to string. Strings are immutable in python, i.e they can't be changed, just made new everytime. Therefore, string operations can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) then you will know that it replaces all occurrences of the first argument by occurences of the second argument.

To compute the complementary DNA strand of a given DNA strand with `str.replace` you have to do the following:

```
dna = "atgcgctagctcattt"

# Replace A by T and T by A.
cdna = dna.replace('a', 'x')
cdna = cdna.replace('t', 'a')
cdna = cdna.replace('x', 't')

# Replace G by C and C by G.
cdna = cdna.replace('g', 'x')
cdna = cdna.replace('c', 'g')
cdna = cdna.replace('x', 'c')
```

However it is probably more efficient to use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
dna = "atgcgctagctcattt"

map = str.maketrans("atgc", "tacg")
cdna = dna.translate(map)
```

which is similar to [Jose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6437980/jose)'s answer. In both cases the result will be:

```
cdna = "tacgcgatcgagtaaa"
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The method str.replace() only takes three arguments, the strings to replace and how many time you want to replace (blank to replace all). You can't change it all at the same time. Try:

```
complementDNA = originalDNA.replace('a' , 'x').replace('t', 'a').replace('x', 't')
```